# Moq dotnetcore - cannot convert from 'method group' to 'Expression<Func<Room, bool>>'

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq, .net-core

I'm trying to setup Moq in a dotnetcore project. I have a generic repository that is called from one of my controllers. I would like to test this an is using moq to setup the call. But I get an error.

The generic repository call that is initiated so `T` is `Room` is:

```
public T GetSingle(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate, params 
Expression<Func<T, object>>[] includeProperties)
```

The call from the `RoomController` looks like:

```
var room = _roomRepository.GetSingle(r => r.Id == id, ro => ro.Image);
```

The mocking part looks like:

```
roomRepositoryMock.Setup(c => c.GetSingle(It.IsAny<Expression<Func<Room, bool>>>(), It.IsAny<Expression<Func<Room, object>>>()))
                            .Returns<Room>(null);
```

But I keep getting errors:

```
RoomControllerTest.cs(62,55): error CS1503: Argument 1: cannot convert from 'method group' to 'Expression<Func<Room, bool>>'
RoomControllerTest.cs(62,70): error CS1503: Argument 2: cannot convert from 'System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<viten_i_senter_backend.Models.Room, object>>' to 'System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<viten_i_senter_backend.Models.Room, object>>'
```

Other posts suggested to add `()` after `It.IsAny<Expression<Func<Room, bool>>>`, but this did not help.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`params` takes an array so change the second expectation to expect any array of expressions `It.IsAny<Expression<Func<Room, object>>[]>()`

```
roomRepositoryMock
    .Setup(c => c.GetSingle(It.IsAny<Expression<Func<Room, bool>>>(), It.IsAny<Expression<Func<Room, object>>[]>()))
    .Returns<Room>(null);
```